# A bit confused on usage of cross products.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, cross-product

I'm reading about angular momentum in physics, and we are given the definition that

$\vec{\tau} = \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$

where $\vec{\tau}$ is torque, $\vec{r}$ is displacement from the origin, and $\vec{F}$ is an incident force.

They later use this result in problem solving, but rather than using a cross product, they simply say

$\tau = Fr$

where these are no longer vectors.

My question is simply this; if all we care about is the magnitude of the result of a cross product, can we just take the answer as a normal scalar product? That is, is it true that

$|\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = |\vec{a}|*|\vec{b}|$

which is what they seem to have done here?

Comment: $\tau = Fr$ is a simplification that assumes that the force is applied at a right angle to the lever arm.  Or $F$ is the component of force at a right angle to the lever arm.  $\tau = F \times r$ is the more general definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The magnitude of the cross product is

$ |\vec{a} \times \vec{b}| = |\vec{a}| |\vec{b}| \sin(\theta)$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. So $\tau = Fr$ is true for $\theta = \pi / 2$.

However, the magnitude of the scalar product is different, it is
$|\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}| = |\vec{a}| |\vec{b}| \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Ah, I see, $\vec{F} $ and $\vec{r}$ were orthagonal. thank you very much.